# How to rewrite two cycles with stream API Java

Tags: java, java-stream

Structure:

```
Accounting
  + Map<Employee, EmployeeCard> getEmployeeCards()

EmployeeCard
  + Map<LocalDate, Report> getReports()

Report
  + double getSalary()
```

I need to calculate salary sum of all reports of all employee cards.

My variant using two cycles:

```
public double getCostsOfEmployeesSalaries() {
  double sumOfSalary = 0;

  for (EmployeeCard card : accounting.getEmployeeCards().values()) {
    Collection<Report> reports = card.getReports().values();

    for (Report report : reports) {
      sumOfSalary += report.getSalary();
    }
  }

  return sumOfSalary;
}
```

Is there any solution to calculate sum using java stream API?

Comment: As an aside: [don't use double for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/2670892)

Comment: Have you tried to google? There are many articles for sum via java stream API

Comment: @Jens yes, I would like to see elegant solution

Comment: While looking on the results you see a lot of *elegant* solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public double getCostsOfEmployeesSalaries() {
    return accounting.getEmployeeCards().values().stream()
            .map(card -> card.getReports().values())
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .mapToDouble(Report::getSalary)
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: Or just `accounting.getEmployeeCards().values().stream() .flatMap(card -> card.getReports().values().stream()) .mapToDouble(Report::getSalary) .sum();` not splitting the flatMap step into two steps.

Comment: Good idea @Holger, is there any performance issue if we make it in two steps?

Comment: No, if there’s a difference, it’s rather negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like that:

```
public double getCostsOfEmployeesSalaries() {
  return accounting.getEmployeeCards().values()
          .stream()
          .mapToDouble(card -> card.getReports().values()
                  .stream()
                  .mapToDouble(Report::getSalary)
                  .sum())
          .sum();
}
```

[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) each card to a double by summing the salary from each report, then sum the resulting double stream. As noted in comments, you should not use `double` when working with money, but [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

Personally i would use the loops instead of streams, but that's just my preference.